# Laravel & MySQL having a join on a join?

Tags: mysql, laravel, join, select

I need to join a table on a already joined table cause the data I need from the other table is also spread in another table. This is my SQL model so far:

[image]

Now I need to join the addresses table the joined child table as well cause I need the address of each child as well. My only problem is, how can I join the table addresses based on the childs.address_id?

I have already tried to to this:

```
INNER JOIN `addresses` AS `addresse_child` ON `childs`.`address_id` = `addresses`.`id`
```

Sadly not working..

My SQL Query so far (DB::getQueryLog())

```
SELECT `assignments`.`id` AS `assignment_id`,
       `assignments`.`persons` AS `assignment_persons`,
       `assignments`.`start_date` AS `assignment_start_date`,
       `assignments`.`end_date` AS `assignment_end_date`,
       `addresses`.`id` AS `address_id`,
       `addresses`.`first_name` AS `address_first_name`,
       `addresses`.`last_name` AS `address_last_name`,
       `addresses`.`company` AS `address_company`,
       `childs`.`id` AS `child_id`,
       `childs`.`address_id` AS `child_address_id`,
       `childs`.`sibling_id` AS `child_sibling_id`,
       `childs`.`height` AS `child_height`,
       `childs`.`weight` AS `child_weight`
FROM `assignments`
INNER JOIN `addresses` ON `assignments`.`address_id` = `addresses`.`id`
INNER JOIN `childs` ON `assignments`.`id` = `childs`.`assignment_id`
WHERE `assignments`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
  AND `addresses`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
  AND `childs`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
```

My Laravel SQL command:

```
$assignment_data =  DB::table('assignments')
            ->join('addresses', 'assignments.address_id',  '=', 'addresses.id')
            ->join('childs', 'assignments.id',  '=', 'childs.assignment_id')
            ->select(
                'assignments.id as assignment_id',
                'assignments.persons as assignment_persons',
                'assignments.start_date as assignment_start_date',
                'assignments.end_date as assignment_end_date',
                'addresses.id as address_id',
                'addresses.first_name as address_first_name',
                'addresses.last_name as address_last_name',
                'addresses.company as address_company',
                'childs.id as child_id',
                'childs.address_id as child_address_id',
                'childs.sibling_id as child_sibling_id',
                'childs.height as child_height',
                'childs.weight as child_weight'

            )
            ->whereNull('assignments.deleted_at')
            ->whereNull('addresses.deleted_at')
            ->whereNull('childs.deleted_at')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do;

```
SELECT `assignments`.`id` AS `assignment_id`,
       `assignments`.`persons` AS `assignment_persons`,
       `assignments`.`start_date` AS `assignment_start_date`,
       `assignments`.`end_date` AS `assignment_end_date`,
       `addresses`.`id` AS `address_id`,
       `addresses`.`first_name` AS `address_first_name`,
       `addresses`.`last_name` AS `address_last_name`,
       `addresses`.`company` AS `address_company`,
       `childs`.`id` AS `child_id`,
       `childs`.`address_id` AS `child_address_id`,
       `childs`.`sibling_id` AS `child_sibling_id`,
       `childs`.`height` AS `child_height`,
       `childs`.`weight` AS `child_weight`
FROM `assignments`
INNER JOIN `addresses` ON `assignments`.`address_id` = `addresses`.`id`
INNER JOIN `childs` ON `assignments`.`id` = `childs`.`assignment_id` AND 
                       `childs`.`address_id` = `addresses`.`id`
WHERE `assignments`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
  AND `addresses`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
  AND `childs`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
```

And in Laravel this can be achieved by doing;

```
 $assignment_data =  DB::table('assignments')
        ->join('addresses', 'assignments.address_id',  '=', 'addresses.id')
        ->join('childs', function($q) { 
               $q->on('assignments.id',  '=', 'childs.assignment_id')
                 ->where('childs.address_id', '=', 'addresses.id');
          })
        ->select(
            'assignments.id as assignment_id',
            'assignments.persons as assignment_persons',
            'assignments.start_date as assignment_start_date',
            'assignments.end_date as assignment_end_date',
            'addresses.id as address_id',
            'addresses.first_name as address_first_name',
            'addresses.last_name as address_last_name',
            'addresses.company as address_company',
            'childs.id as child_id',
            'childs.address_id as child_address_id',
            'childs.sibling_id as child_sibling_id',
            'childs.height as child_height',
            'childs.weight as child_weight'

        )
        ->whereNull('assignments.deleted_at')
        ->whereNull('addresses.deleted_at')
        ->whereNull('childs.deleted_at')
        ->get();
```

However you should note that by doing INNER JOINS you will only get results if there are rows in each table. You maybe better off doing LEFT JOINS instead, depending on how your data is required.

Comment: Thanks mate, working. Except you have a typo. Needs to be ``childs`.`address_id` = `addresses`.`id``. You have forgotten two gravis. However, how can I select the `fist_name` and `last_name` of a child?

Comment: Where are you storing the first name and last name of the child? On the childs table?

Comment: No, address table. Thats why I need to join the address table on the childs table

Comment: When an assignment is made, it looks as though one or more addresses is added, and for each address there are a number of children at that address? Would it not be easier to record the child's name on the childs table?

Comment: Yeah, I also figured it out... And one assignment can always just have one (invoice) address